# Quartz default configurations in JBossAS-5.x

Tags: configuration, jboss, default, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz Scheduler available in JBossAS-5.x. I want to change default configurations of Quartz. E.g. Threads and all stuffs. But I am unable to find the default configuration file in JBoss. Kindly suggest some pointers on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the quartz source code repository: http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/quartz/trunk/quartz-jboss/src/main/java/org/quartz/ee/jmx/jboss/doc-files/quartz-service.xml

HIH